# How do I change the gridview selected item background color?

Tags: asp.net

How do I change the gridview selected item background color in Asp.net web applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try calling a javascript function on the `onmouseover` event. [This website](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahakgupta/how-to-change-color-of-rows-in-gridview-on-mouseover/) has a quick example:

On the server side:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] =
            "javascript:mouseovercolor(this);";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] =
            "javascript:mouseoutcolor(this);";
    }
}
```

On the client side:

```
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
    function mouseovercolor(mytxt) {
        mytxt.bgColor = 'Orange';
    }
    function mouseoutcolor(mytxt) {
        element.bgColor = 'White';
    }
</script>
```

**Edited:** [This site has a nice example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/209416/Make-the-entire-GridView-Row-clickable-and-selecta) on how to make it work with the `onClick` event:

Server side:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){
    // javascript function to call on row-click event
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:void SelectRow(this);");
  }
 }
```

Client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         // format current row
         function SelectRow(row) {
             var _selectColor = "#303030";
             var _normalColor = "#909090";
             var _selectFontSize = "3em";
             var _normalFontSize = "2em";
             // get all data rows - siblings to current
             var _rows = row.parentNode.childNodes;
             // deselect all data rows
             try {
                 for (i = 0; i < _rows.length; i++) {
                     var _firstCell = _rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                     _firstCell.style.color = _normalColor;
                     _firstCell.style.fontSize = _normalFontSize;
                     _firstCell.style.fontWeight = "normal";
                 }
             }
             catch (e) { }
             // select current row (formatting applied to first cell)
             var _selectedRowFirstCell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
             _selectedRowFirstCell.style.color = _selectColor;
             _selectedRowFirstCell.style.fontSize = _selectFontSize;
             _selectedRowFirstCell.style.fontWeight = "bold";
         }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks but i have that error when i debug it:Error 2 Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.

Comment: Are you using master pages? if so, just for troubleshooting purposes, move the javascript block to the master page (head tag)

Comment: thank you my friend for your help, but when i click another cell in grid-view, i wanna reset value for the previous cell and apply the new value for the new cell.

Comment: What do you mean with resetting value for the previous cell? is this still related to selecting the row?

Comment: yes, it is still related to selecting row.                       for example : i have gridview
(category
cat1
cat2
cat3)
i want when i click on cat1,it must be changed its color,
and when i click on cat3 reset cat1 to default values and cat3 must be changed its color.. thank but i am still beginner.

Comment: Yes that's what the code is supposed to do, make sure GridView1_RowDataBound fires on each postback. Also check if there was any javascript error (IE shows a yellow icon at the bottom of the page). You could also try calling alert('Method called!') on the method, just to make sure the javascript code is executed.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that in aspx page under the GridView tag:

```
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Orange" />
```

But if you want different color on mouse over or mouse out then try the following in the code behind under RowDataBound event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.backgroundColor='orangered'");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='white'");
        }
    }
```

Also check out this link if you want to select a row without clicking on the buttons: [ASP.NET: Selecting a Row in a GridView](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/01/25/asp-net-selecting-a-row-in-a-gridview.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Habib.OSU , i used that code in (GridView1_RowDataBound)Event, but i want when i click on item in gridview, it must highlight and still highlight until i click another one.

Comment: @Gandhi, check out this link, http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/01/25/asp-net-selecting-a-row-in-a-gridview.aspx I have also update the answer with the link