# highlight selected row in gridview without postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I hav a gridview in asp.net which updates a preview picture whenever it is clicked. this works without a postback and I do it this way:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender,System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
      e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
      e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
      e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
      e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "RetrievePicture(" + GVmail.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString() + ",this)";
     }
  }
```

However, I want the user to be able to see which row is selected and therefore displaying the image.. (so I want to row to stay highlighted). and then when another row is selected, i want that row to go back to normal and the newly selected one to be highlighted.

how can I do this without a postback?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268891/how-do-i-change-the-gridview-selected-item-background-color

Answer (score 0):

See it

```
   for (int i = 0; i < gridview.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow row;
        row = gridview.Rows[i];
        if (row.Cells[1].Text.Equals("ABSENT"))
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed;
            row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            row.Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
```

migth help you !!

Comment: I need it ot be done on client side... this doesnt do what I need

Comment: possible with onClientClick property